# Filtering RDD Based on condition and extracting matched data in Spark python

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

I have the data like,

```
cl_id      cn_id        cn_value
10004,     77173296     ,390.0
10004,     77173299     ,376.0
10004,     77173300     ,0.0
20005,     77173296     ,0.0
20005,     77173299     ,6.0
2005,      77438800     ,2.0
```

Cl_id IDs: 10004    ,20005

Filter by 10004

```
10004,     77173296     ,390.0
10004,     77173299     ,376.0
```

Filter by 20005

```
20005,    77173296    ,0.0
20005,    77173299     ,6.0
```

Now I want the return RDD like,

```
10004,cn_id,x1(77173296.value,77173300.value) ==> 10004,77173296,390.0,376.0
20005,cn_id,x1(77173296.value,77173300.value) ==> 20005,77173296,0.0,6.0
```

And I want to perform some operation on this `return_RDD`:

```
 def cal_for(rdd_list):
     #list.map(position1).filter(cn_id for this formula)-> calculate that formula -> store in a separate RDD -> Return that RDD

     rdd_list = rdd_list.map(lambda line:line.split(','))
     new_list = rdd_list.map(lambda x: (x[0]+', '+x[1],float(x[2])))
     new_list = rdd_list.filter(lambda x: x[1] == '77173296' && x[1] ==  '77173299')
     ## then  get the  RDD containing respective cn_values for cn_id 77173296 & cn_id 77173299
     ## and apply the following formula whre a=77173296.value b=77173299.value for cl_id 1004

    try:
        # want to process RDD with this  Formula
        return ((float(a)/float(a+b))*100)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0

#return or save cal_RDD
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of filtering the RDD twice, modifying and recombining the resulting RDDs, simply group by id, then map over the values to make any changes you need. If you want to further limit the results based on some criteria, then perform a filter while mapping.

I can't really give you a more precise answer as:

a) It doesn't look like you've really tried to implement this yet, and
b) I'm not entirely certain what you want.

Comment: As i am new to this will facing me the problems. and from input Rdd i just want to filter the result based on cl_id and pass the proccesed Rdd to cal_fo()

Comment: You may want to read up a bit more on Scala and Spark. For instance, you don't need the return keyword, and manipulating the data once you have the RDD is relatively simple. I'm not entirely sure if your question is a Spark one, or if you want somebody to write your logic for you. I think you should describe what it is you're hoping to achieve (without referring to actual values).

Comment: Really Thanks Steven. I will work  more on it and wiil try to simplify and implement it. Thanks alot.