# Spark operations map,flatmap,filter,ReduceByKey, using python

Tags: python, apache-spark

I want to some Spark filter and transformation for that I have the sample data,

```
657483, 888888, 9
657483, 888889, 10
657484, 888888, 20
657484, 888889, 30
```

For each `x[0]` I want to check condition to match `x[1] == '888888' && x[1] == '888889'` and get relative x[2] so the output will look like,

```
657483,9,10
657484,20,30
```

I want to do this using spark map,filter transformation. so i tried

```
result = (file1
    .map(lambda x: (x.split(",")[0],x))
    .groupByKey()
    .map(lambda x: (x[0], list(x[1])))  
    .sortByKey('true')
    .coalesce(1).map(lambda line: (line[0], if(line[1] == "888888"), and (line[1] == "888889"))).saveAsTextFile('hdfs://localhost:9000/filter'))
```

It gives me the results like,

```
657483,false,false

657484,false,false
```

How can I extract the `x[0]` and `x[2]` which contain `x[1] == 888888 && x[1] == '888889'`. How can we apply if condition to filter the result.

Comment: So read some documentation, give it a try and ask questions if you run into problems. You can't simply come here asking for somebody to do it for you without even showing any evidence of trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def filterfunct(x):
    if (len(x[1]) != 2):
        return false
    else:
        if (x[1][0][0] == 888888 and x[1][1][0] == 888889) or (x[1][1][0] == 888888 and x[1][0][0] == 888889) :
           return true
        else:
           return false
def mapfunct(x):
    if (x[1][0][0] == 888888):
        return (x[0],x[1][0][1],x[1][1][1])
    else:
        return (x[0],x[1][1][1],x[1][0][1])





result = (file1
.map(lambda x: (x.split(",")[0],(int(x.split(",")[1]),int(x.split(",")[2]))))
.groupByKey()
.map(lambda x: (x[0], filter(lambda y: y[0]==888888 or y[0]==888889, list(x[1]))))  
.filter(filterfunct)
.map(mapfunct)  
.sortByKey('true')
.saveAsTextFile('hdfs://localhost:9000/filter'))
```

The `groupByKey()` will give the result like this `{(657483,[(888888, 9),(888889, 10)]}`, where `(x,y)` is a tuple and `[x,y]` is a list. However you do not know the order in which the list is constructed (most of the times it follows the order in which they are read, but if two consecutive lines end up in different partitions you might get them reversed)

Comment: The values are grouped by key now, And i applied if condition in map function but it is giving me 657483,false,false like this. What is the perfect way to apply if condition in map function in python

Comment: See my modified answer if it works for you

Comment: Thanks Radu lonescu, code is executed but output file is coming blank..

Comment: Can you give the output of this `result = (file1
.map(lambda x: (x.split(",")[0],(x.split(",")[1],x.split(",")[2])))
.groupByKey()
.map(lambda x: (x[0], list(x[1]))).take(10).saveAsTextFile('hdfs://localhost:9000/filter')) `

Comment: coming like (u'657483', [(u'   888888', u'9'), (u'    888889', u'10'), (u'    888890', u'8'), (u'   888891', u'4'), (u'   888892', u'8') ])                           (u'657484', [(u'   888888', u'20'), (u'    888889', u'30'), (u'    888890', u'67'), (u'   888891', u'67'), (u'   888892', u'76') ])

Comment: The strings cotained a whitespace and the comparison was giving false. I changed them to numbers. This solution works if all records have a 888888 and 888889 in them. If this is not the case I would recommend the replacing  `lambda x: (x[1][0][0] == 888888 and x[1][1][0] == 888889) or (x[1][1][0] == 888888 and x[1][0][0] == 888889) ` with a regular function which returns false if the list has size less then 2.

Comment: This new version should work in all cases

Comment: Thanks Alot Radu lonescu, getting correct result now.

Comment: We needed some iterations to get it to work :P

Comment: Yes But it so hard to understand me. like u have use x[1][0][0] then x[1][1][0].. i have to go through it and if you look on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34743647/spark-rdd-filter-and-mapping-using-python i have to apply our computed output to some formulas..

Comment: It is because python use the same for accesing tuples and list. After the `groupBy` your RDD looks like this `{ (657483 , [(888888, 9),(888889, 10)]}`, which is made out of Tuple2, second element `x[1]` is a list. To select first element of list you do `x[1][0]`. Each element of the list is a Tuple2. To select first element of the tuple I add `x[1][0][0]`. `(x,y)` is a Tuple2. `[ x, y ]` is a list. The output is a Tuple3 `(x,y,z)`.

Comment: the link i posted is wrong , applying RDD to formula this is that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34722224/filtering-rdd-based-on-condition-and-extracting-matched-data-in-spark-python